# What are the languages supported by db file

Tags: android, sqlite, localization, cordova

I have an excel sheet in a chinese langugage. This is to be used to create a db for the phonegap application. I create this db manually. What are the ways I can do this?

1. Should I convert the excel sheet to unicode and store it in the db(will the db support this unicode format?)...and retrieve the unicode and deocde it back the simplified chinese language?
2. Or does the db file support different languages? Will i be able to store the data in the chinese language itself??

Summarizing, UI is to be changed to the chinese language. and I have no idea about the language. I have an excel sheet with data. This is to be displayed on the HTML.

Comment: Either Excel file formats and SQLite database files are Unicode. Be careful with convertion and everything should run fine!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the .db can itself hold characters of various languages. This can be fetched and displayed in the app as well. It can be entered using SQLite Databrowser.